# One dataset, two charts?

Tags: google-visualization

I have one dataset and want to create two charts. Where I'm struggeling is how to assign the dataset components to series resp axis:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var gcParamsHvTimeDiv = document.getElementById('gcDivParamsHvTime');
  var gcParamsHvPathDiv = document.getElementById('gcDivParamsHvPath');
  
  var dataParamsHv = new google.visualization.DataTable();

dataParamsHv.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time');
dataParamsHv.addColumn('number', 'Height');
dataParamsHv.addColumn('number', 'Speed');
dataParamsHv.addColumn('number', 'Flightpath');

dataParamsHv.addRows([
 [[16,07,35],170,0.00,0.00], /*...*/ [[17,35,55],248,0.87,106.36]
]);
```

Now I want to create two charts: "Height and Speed vs Time" and "Height and Speed vs Flight path" based on the given dataset.

```
  var gcParamsHvTimeOptions = {
    title: 'Height and speed - time',
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    chartArea: { left: '7%', top: '9%', right: '7%', bottom: '9%', backgroundColor: {strokeWidth: 1, stroke: '#666'}},
    // Gives each series an axis that matches the vAxes number below.
    series: {
      0: {targetAxisIndex: 0, lineDashStyle: [3, 1]},
      1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
    },
    vAxes: {
      0: {title: 'Height [m]'},
      1: {title: 'Speed [km/h]'}
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time [h:m]',
      titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
    },
    vAxis: {
      titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true},
      gridlines: {count: 7},
      minorGridlines: {count: 0}
    }
  };

  var gcParamsHvPathOptions = {
    title: 'Height and speed - flight path',
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    chartArea: { left: '7%', top: '9%', right: '7%', bottom: '9%', backgroundColor: {strokeWidth: 1, stroke: '#666'}},
    // Gives each series an axis that matches the vAxes number below.
    series: {
      0: {targetAxisIndex: 0, lineDashStyle: [3, 1]},
      1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
    },
    vAxes: {
      0: {title: 'Height [m]'},
      1: {title: 'Speed [km/h]'}
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Flight path [km]',
      titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
    },
    vAxis: {
      titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true},
      gridlines: {count: 7},
      minorGridlines: {count: 0}
    }
  };

  function gcDrawParams() {
    var chartParamsHvTime = new google.visualization.LineChart(gcParamsHvTimeDiv);
    chartParamsHvTime.draw(dataParamsHv, gcParamsHvTimeOptions);
    var chartParamsHvPath = new google.visualization.LineChart(gcParamsHvPathDiv);
    chartParamsHvPath.draw(dataParamsHv, gcParamsHvPathOptions);
  }
  gcDrawParams();
}
```

So how to assign proper indices to `series` resp. `vAxes`?

I got it working with two different datasets, but this implies redundant data (height, speed), I want to avoid.

Thank you
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use one dataset for multiple charts, manipulate the DataTable's view for each chart by specifying the column indices to be used.

```js
function gcDrawParams() {
  var viewForTime = new google.visualization.DataView(dataParamsHv);
  viewForTime.setColumns([0, 1, 2]);  // Time, Height, Speed

  var chartParamsHvTime = new google.visualization.LineChart(gcParamsHvTimeDiv);
  chartParamsHvTime.draw(viewForTime, gcParamsHvTimeOptions);

  var viewForPath = new google.visualization.DataView(dataParamsHv);
  viewForPath.setColumns([3, 1, 2]);  // Flightpath, Height, Speed

  var chartParamsHvPath = new google.visualization.LineChart(gcParamsHvPathDiv);
  chartParamsHvPath.draw(viewForPath, gcParamsHvPathOptions);
}
```

This way, you can maintain one source of truth for your data while presenting it in different ways.

Comment: Thank you so much @suchislife! Works perfectly now :-)